# How to make a JavaScript class or function that will make the following code work? I can't use promise and await

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is what should be output to console:

```
1 hello
2 a
3 b
```

And here is the code for which i should make a class or a function:

```
var d = new deferred();
d.then(function(res) {
  console.log("1 ", res);
  var d1 = new deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    d1.resolve("a");
  }, 150);
  return d1;
});
d.then(function(res) {
  console.log("2 ", res);
  return "b";
});
d.then(function(res) {
  console.log("3 ", res);
  return "c";
});
d.resolve("hello");
```

I should create a class or a
function with name "deferred"

I've already done almost everything except i can't make it get the result from `setTimeout`
function.

```
function deferred() {
  this.arrfunc = [];
  this.buffstr = null;
  this.bufffunc;
  this.result;
  this.then = function(callback) {
    this.arrfunc.push(callback);
  }
  this.wait = function() {
    while (this.buffstr == null) {}
    return this.buffstr;
  }
  this.resolve = function(str) {
    this.buffstr = str;
    while (this.arrfunc.length != 0) {
      //console.log(typeof(this.buffstr));
      if (typeof(this.buffstr) === "object") {
        this.buffstr = this.buffstr.wait();
      }
      this.bufffunc = this.arrfunc.shift();
      this.buffstr = this.bufffunc(this.buffstr);
    }
  }
}
```

The main problem in my implemenetation that its somehow stuck in while loop. And don't want to get a result after setTimeout expired.

Comment: Not using promise and await is part of the my task.

Comment: You have an infinite loop in `this.wait`, since nothing else can update `this.buffstr` while it's looping.

Comment: @Barmar - Code never calls `this.wait()` though. I saw that too, but couldn't grock the call.

Comment: @RandyCasburn It calls it here: `this.buffstr = this.buffstr.wait();` when `this.buffstr` is an object rather than a string.

Comment: @Barmar - sure, I don't see where `this.buffstr` is ever assigned an object value. Sorry for being obtuse. Every return assigns a string to `this.buffstr`.

Comment: `this.buffstr = str`. So it will be an object if you call `d.resolve(anObject)` instead of `d.resolve(aString)`

Comment: I see it in the very first `.then()` returns a deferred object.

Comment: Looks like an interview question about how to implement a Promise from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like maybe you are making this too complicated with all the different state properties. If these are you only requirements, you really only need a queue of callbacks to hold on to all the functions passed into `then()`. Like regular promises you need to act differently depending on whether the callback returns a regular value or another `deferred` instance.

```js
function deferred() {
  this.callbacks = []
}
deferred.prototype.then = function(cb) {
  this.callbacks.push(cb)
}
deferred.prototype.resolve = function(val) {
  let f = this.callbacks.shift()
  if (f) {
    let n = f(val)
    if (n instanceof deferred) n.then((v) => this.resolve(v))
    else this.resolve(n)
  }
}

var d = new deferred("one");
d.then(function(res) {
  console.log("1 ", res);
  var d1 = new deferred("two");

  setTimeout(function() {
    d1.resolve("a");
  }, 550);
  return d1;
});
d.then(function(res) {
  console.log("2 ", res);
  return "b";
});
d.then(function(res) {
  console.log("3 ", res);
  return "c";
});
d.resolve("hello")
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now i need to understand why is yours code work:)